# Bash script - Automatically enter user input (password of keystore)

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, centos, user-input

I know this has been asked before but almost only workarounds have been provided. None that solved my problem just yet.

I'm trying to create my own `.sh` file which will generate an `apk`. After using jarsigner it asks for a password of my keystore. Now the security on this part doesn't play a role a.t.m. so I was just wondering, how can I (either remove the password of my `.keystore` file or enter the password as plain text) achieve this?

The full command:

```
jarsigner -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -verbose -keystore keyForApk.keystore 
  apk/android-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

Where it then prompts me the following:

```
Enter Passphrase for keystore:
```

Now via which command can I enter this dynamically after the jarsigner command?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jarsigner, but it's *possible* that it's trying to directly read your terminal; test it out with `echo | jarsigner -sigalg .... rest of it`

Comment: for testing you can provide passwords in the command line with options `-storepass` and `-keypass`. see `man jarsigner`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [expect](https://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/) utility to automate your passphrase input. Create launcher script `auto-jar.sh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect

# Wait for finish forever after send password
set timeout -1
# Put your jarsigner command here
spawn jarsigner ...
expect "Enter Passphrase for keystore: "
send "your jar password\r"
# Wait for jarsigner command finish
expect eof
# Return relevant exit code of jarsigner command
# , useful if you want continue next command only after signed successfully with `&&`
foreach {pid spawnid os_error_flag exit_code} [wait] break
exit "$exit_code"
```

Then `chmod +x auto-jar.sh` to make it executable and run with `./auto-jar.sh`. Or run as `expect auto-jar.sh`.

Comment: "spawn" is not found. I installed expect and "expect" is found

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` wants a password, but I don't want to hard-code it into scripts which- amongst others issues- could be a pain from a maintenance perspective when you change a password.

Since I use a Docker-Compose "secrets" file to keep the MariaDB root password out of Git, I just `cat` that into an expanding variable and the command executes without prompting for user input:

```
mysqldump -h192.168.2.2 -p"$(cat /docker-compose-dir/mariadb_root_pswd.txt)" -uroot wordpressDBname > /backupsDirectory/wordpressDBname_`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S`.sql
```

This solution also serves to keep root passwords out of my bash scripts. Tested with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the `mariadb-client`